# Nash inequality on a compact domain?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have come across a few papers that make use of the [Nash inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Nash_inequality) for functions on a compact domain.    Unfortunately, nobody cites a reference for the proof of this result.  Is going from the classical Nash inequality on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to that on compact domains so trivial?

I'd really appreciate any references you know of.

EDIT:  This is the statement I am looking for

Let $\mathcal{D} = \mathbb{T}^n$ be the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with periodic boundary conditions.  There exist constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that  such that for $f \in H^1(\mathcal{D})$ then
$$||f||_{2}^{1 + \frac{n}{2}} \leq ||f||_1 \left(C_1||f||_{2}^2 + C_2||\nabla f||_2^2\right)^{\frac{n}{4}}$$

Comment: Could you provide a precise statement of the inequality you want a reference for?

Comment: In particular, if the functions on the compact domain are assumed to vanish on the boundary, then the inequality on $\mathbb{R}^n$ applies directly.

Comment: @Deane: You're right I should have specified that the functions should be periodic.

Comment: You're effectively asking for the Nash inequality on a closed manifold. Cover the manifold by co-ordinate charts, fix a partition of unity subordinate to these charts. The inequality on the manifold then follows by applying the inequality on $\mathbb{R}^n$ on each co-ordinate chart to each compactly supported piece of the function and adding everything up.

Comment: It is not clear you can add pieces up since both sides of the inequality are non linear. You might use convexity for the left-hand side, but the right-hand side of a sum of functions you be harder to estimate.

Comment: The inequality $\sum_i^N a_i b_i \le N(\sum a_i)(\sum b_i)$, where everything is nonnegative, is very helpful here.

Comment: Another approach is to derive the Nash inequality from the Sobolev inequality for functions on the manifold using the Holder inequality.

Comment: The Nash inequality is a particular case of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequalities, so you can look up the proofs for that.

Comment: @Deane: thanks for your suggestions, but doesn't the Nash inequality only follow from the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality when $n\geq 3$?.  

Comment: What goes wrong when $n = 2$?

Answer (score 2):

The original Nash inequality in $\mathbb R^d$ is
$$\|\nabla f\|_2 \|f\|_1^{2/d} \geq c \|f\|_2^{1+2/d}$$
It is proved in this article: *Nash, J. Continuity of solutions of parabolic and elliptic equations. Amer. J. Math. 80 1958 931–954.*

The inequality is proved by the beginning of the paper. You can see it by the top of page 936. It is a very simple argument using the Fourier transform, so you can try to work it out in your periodic setting using Fourier series.

Note that the function $f \equiv 1$ fails the original Nash inequality in a compact domain. The extra term you have in yours is a correction for the compact case that is not necessary in the full space $\mathbb R^d$

Comment: @Luis,  thanks for your information.  Yes, the original Fourier transform doesn't seem to translate very well to fourier series.   There is another proof of the Nash inequality which I found in a paper of Stroock proved using estimates on the solution of the Heat equation.  I'm attempting to adapt this one.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes one has to roll up his sleeves and get his hands dirty in analysis.

So here is the estimate you need:

$$ \|f\|_2^2=(\sum_{|\xi|\le R}+\sum_{|\xi|>R}) |\hat f(\xi)|^2\ll_n R^n\sup_{\xi} |\hat f(\xi)|^2 + R^{-2}\sum_{|\xi|>R} |\xi|^2|\hat f(\xi)|^2 $$

which in turn is bounded by

$$ \|f\|_2^2\ll_n R^n \|f\|_1^2+R^{-2}\|\nabla f\|_2^2. $$

Now taking $R$ to be optimal a  la Nash, you get

$$ \|f\|_2\ll_n \|f\|_1^{\frac{2}{n+2}}\|\nabla f\|_2^{\frac{n}{n+2}} $$

which is even stronger than your inequality (note we can dispense with the term $\|f\|_2^2$ on the RHS.